# VBA nested For Each loop through array - syntax

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, nested

I have multiple pivot tables on a sheet, I'm wanting to loop through all of the pivot field items on 2 of those pivot tables (tables 4 and 5). I created 2 PivotItems variable objects, put them in an array, and I want to do a nested For Each loop iterating over each object in the array, then iterating over each pivot item in each array object. I keep getting a Run-time error '424': Object required at line 11 `For Each PvI in Item`

Here's the code:

```
Dim PvtTbl4, PvtTbl5 As PivotItems
Set PvtTbl4 = Worksheets("Main").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("dayname").PivotItems
Set PvtTbl5 = Worksheets("Main").PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("dayname").PivotItems

Dim PivotArray As Variant
PivotArray = Array(PvtTbl4, PvtTbl5)
Dim PvI As PivotItem
Dim Item As Variant

For Each Item In PivotArray
  For Each PvI In Item  //<-- error
  //do something
Next PvI
Next Item
```

Comment: Seems like one of those elements in the array is `Nothing`. Did you check that with the debugger? you can insert before the problematic line: `Debug.Assert Not Item Is Nothing` or so.

Comment: I did, and you're correct. This block is the result of me trying to refactor a working block where I had 2 separate loops, 1 for each Pivot table; those objects worked.  Putting them into an array is where I ran into problems.

Comment: BTW `Dim PvtTbl4, PvtTbl5 As PivotItems` == > `Dim PvtTbl4 As PivotItems, PvtTbl5 As PivotItems`. Wont likely solve the problem but clearly this was your intent, otherwise PvtTbl4 was declared as `Variant`